# Why do I have a second text cursor in Firefox?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I haven't tested any other browser but this happens in Firefox: There always seems to be a cursor out of place almost where the cursor is supposed to be. If I try to type when it is flashing in the wrong spot, nothing will happen.

I'm not sure if it's a visual bug or what?

---

Here is a screenshot from Super User:

[image]

---

Here is a screenshot from YouTube:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have "Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages" enabled.

To disable it, go to `about:preferences` and uncheck "Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages" (under "Browsing" section).